# CoreData add object to a to-many Relationship error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, object-relationships

I have a CoreData object Player with a to-many relationship to goals. I am trying to add a goal object like so,

```
Goal *fg =(Goal*)[self.database createGoalObject]; //Custom function 

Player* player = (Player*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:self.database.managedObjectContext];

[player addGoalsObject:fg];
```

My app is breaking with the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d90f00'
```

A po at the debug prompt shows that 0x8d90f00 is a Goal object. My questions are:

1. why is core data sending a message to the Goal object?
2. why is the goals relationship for Player initializing to nil? Should it not be an empty set till loaded?
3. Do I have to override the addGoalsObject in Player.h to manually set the value?

Comment: Can you show `createGoalObject` method?

Answer (score 1):

The error specifically says that something tried to call the `entity` method on an `__NSCFSet`. In other words, the object at `0x8d90f00` is an NSSet of some type.

You are being slightly mislead by the output of `po 0x8d90f00` because NSSet's `description` method will include the description of the objects it contains, wrapped in `{(` and `)}` characters.

Had you done `po [0x8d90f00 class]` it would have responded `NSSet` or `NSMutableSet`.

Your createGoalObject is returning a set.

Comment: You're right. po 0x8d90f00 is showing the description of the object it contains. po [0x8d90f00 class] does respond with __NSCFSet. Not sure I am any closer to resolving the issue though.